# reading and writing to the same file c++

Tags: c++, fstream

I have small app which at begin will read text file (with serialized objects) in which im storing some obejcts (im doing it by overloading << and >> operators). This text file has to be updated each time new object is created:

```
fstream m_haystackMapFile;
m_haystackMapfile.open(haystackMapFile,  std::ios::binary | std::ios::in | std::ios::out);
```

first i do read:

```
WHaystackFile f;
m_haystackMapfile.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

std::copy(std::istream_iterator<WHaystackFile>(m_haystackMapfile), std::istream_iterator<WHaystackFile>(), std::back_inserter(m_haystackFiles));

std::cout << "reading input file, no of files: " << m_haystackFiles.size() << std::endl;
for(std::vector<WHaystackFile>::iterator it = m_haystackFiles.begin(); it != m_haystackFiles.end(); ++it){
    f = *it;
    std::cout << "key: " << f.getKey() << " cookie: " << f.getCookie()  << " path: " << f.getPath()  << " size: " << f.getSize()<< std::endl;
}
```

then after creating new object I do write:

```
void WhaystackMap::addEntry(WHaystackFile &f){
    std::cout << "adding entry to index file" << std::endl;
    m_haystackMapfile.seekp(std::ios::end);
    m_haystackMapfile << f;
    std::cout << f;

}
```

unfortunatelly file in which I want to write is never updated and it always has size 0. Maybe im messing up something, but after googling i can't find answer how to using fstream I can read and write to same file...

any help is welcomed :)

regards
J.

Comment: I think that should be m_haystackMapfile.seekp(0, std::ios::end);

Comment: @rici Exact.  But the istream iterator first reads the file util the end, setting the stream in failmode.  So the seekp() and the subsequent output will not even occur.

Comment: @Christophe: Right you are. Should have read more code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the wrong usage of [`seekp()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/seekp/?kw=seekp):

- you use it with one single parameter `ios::end` in `m_haystackMapfile.seekp(std::ios::end)`
- but single parameter only works for absolute positionning.  So `ios::end` is converted into an integer and will locate you at an unexpected place (on my implementation it's 2).
- you have to use `m_haystackMapfile.seekp(0, std::ios::end)` instead

There is another problem:  the `istream_iterator<>()` that you use in your `std::copy()` will read the stream until it reaches its end.  So the failbit and eofbit will be set.

Connsequently, no stream operation will succed until you clear the flags:   `m_haystackMapfile.clear();`

Answer (score 4):

It's very important to check success of I/O operations. For example, if `seekp` is unable to seek to the desired position, it will set the `failbit`, and then all subsequent writes will fail. Or, as @Christophe points out, if you read the file to the end, you will cause the eofbit to be set. Unless that bit is cleared, the next I/O operation (even seekp) will fail.

Even if the eofbit had been reset, the seek probably would fail because the call should have been `m_haystackMapfile.seekp(0, std::ios::end);`.